# How to convert List<Member> to JSON and send to JavaScript highcharts?

Tags: java, json, list

am new to this java world.. i just wanted to know how to convert a db populated list to json and then call this json in javascript?

i saw many examples inputting data manually into list, but i dnt understand how to convert this list.. should i create another method or something else?

Thanks for your patience and reply.

For example, i have a list of type members

```
public List<Member> getMember() throws SQLException
{
       //connection 
       List<Member> listmember = new ArrayList<Member>();

    ps = con.prepareStatement(myquery);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next())
    {
      Member fsta = new Member();
      fsta.setName(rs.getString(2));
      fsta.setJan(rs.getString(6));
      fsta.setFeb(rs.getString(7));
      fsta.setMar(rs.getString(8));
      listmember .add(fsta);
    }// end of while

    return listmember ;
}
```

Now i want to convert the listmember to json, in return call the json in my javascript.

Hope this makes it clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create list to json array as follow:

```
List<Member> listmember= getMember();

JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject(listmember);
```

refer [Simple List to Json example](http://csm2kh.blogspot.in/2008/10/simple-list-to-json-example.html)

then to send it to your wepage. in your webpage you can pass it through javascript.

Comment: hi hemant, thanks for this answer but yet it does not help me.. i have a method whereby i populate my list with values in the database.
I want to convert this list to json and not print out the values using System.out.println

Comment: jsonObject  is a converted list in json you can use it to webpage to send through javascript

Comment: how to convert the list then, using a method? how to call the java method in jsf?

Comment: in a commandbutton or commandlink you can call it as  <h:commandLink value="create jsonobject" action="#{classname.methodname}"/>

Comment: and how to call in javascript?

Comment: you can store jsonarray to class attribute say jsonobj and access in webpage as `#{classname.jsonobj}`

Comment: i tried this, but it seems that javascript does not read the bean itself!

Comment: you can pass #{classname.jsonobj} to any javascript function

Comment: please review the question now

Comment: hi, when am using these libraries my project is not running.  Am using Jboss AS 7, java version 1.7.02 and jre 7.. Eclipse
Can you help me out please?